# JS Proxy: Operating on entire get path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a remote key/value store with a simple `.get()/.put()` interface. I want to call `someProxyObject.route1.route2.route3` and have this resolve to a call to `storageObject.retrieve(["route1", "route2", "route3"])`. The goal is to treat the remote storage like a local object. I am currently using the following code to collect the route.

```js
var validator = {
  route: [],
  get(target, key) {
      this.route.push(key)
      console.log(String(this.route), "get");
      return new Proxy(target, validator)
  },
  set (target, key, value) {
      this.route.push(key)
      console.log(String(this.route), "set");
      return false
  },
  deleteProperty (target, key) {
      this.route.push(key)
      console.log(String(this.route), "delete");
      return target;
  }
}
let storage = new Proxy({}, validator);
storage.p1.p2.p3.p4 = 1
validator.route = []
storage.p1.p2.p3.p4
```

As you can see from running the above code, when I set or delete a value, there is a recursion of `get` calls and then a resolving `delete/set` call. The issue is having no resolving call for a simple `get` chain. Can you devise a method to act upon the final `.routeX` to allow for a final resolution?  EDIT: My goal is to avoid placing a final call like `.resolve` at the end of the chain

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't quite answer your question, but you could just add an extra `.route` to resolve the chain. You don't even need a setter:

```js
function createStorage() {
  const route = [];

  function createProxy() {
    return new Proxy({}, {
      get(_0, key) {
        if (key === 'route') {
          return route;
        }
        route.push(key);
        return createProxy();
      }
    });
  }

  return createProxy();
}

const storage = createStorage();

console.log(storage.p1.p2.p3.route); //=> ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
```

In the same way, you could also have a `clear` key that will reset the route array so you don't access the state directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm looking specifically for a way to treat storage like a normal object rather than requiring the resolving statement

Comment: It may be possible by using the setter to know about the last property, but that seems to add more code than a resolving property.